# Can´t exclude duplicated library dependencies in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I´m using multiple Calendar libraries for a demo aplication for android.
Including [Flexible Calendar](https://github.com/p-v/FlexibleCalendar) and [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid), both uses [Infinite View Pager](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager/) library, and it gives me `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'` because f the duplicated class files:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/antonyt/infiniteviewpager/InfinitePagerAdapter;
```

So I enabled multidex and I was trying to exlude that library from one of those libraries but I can´t get the expected result.

I tried:

```
compile ('com.p_v:flexiblecalendar:1.2.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager', module: 'library'
}
```

and this

```
compile ('com.p_v:flexiblecalendar:1.2.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager'
}
```

and this

```
compile ('com.p_v:flexiblecalendar:1.2.1'){
    exclude group: 'antonyt.infiniteviewpager'
}
```

But it doesn´t work. Im still getting the MultiDex error
Which one is the right way to acomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It can't work** since these libs don't have the module `com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager` inside.

You can check the dependencies in the build.gradle of each library.
Also you can find the source of the `InfinitePagerAdapter` in each library (check [link1](https://github.com/p-v/FlexibleCalendar/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/antonyt/infiniteviewpager) and [link2](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/tree/master/caldroid/src/main/java/com/antonyt/infiniteviewpager)).

Since the libraries seems to be not updated and quite easy to build you can download one of these as a local module in your project avoiding the duplicate.

Comment: Right. I already checked them and both includes the classes directly on the src. I thought it could be solved by gradle. Thank you.